# Jumping ImageView when dragging in Android

Tags: android

Ok. So I'm doing something very similar to what the person at [Strange jumping values for onTouchListener using a RelativeLayout in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295271/strange-jumping-values-for-ontouchlistener-using-a-relativelayout-in-android) is doing. Unfortunately I'm having the same problem as that person. They supposedly solved the problem but didn't really post a solution. Does anyone by chance know how to fix this problem?

Comment: The sample app API Demos shows you how to do this.  I would suggest taking a look at that implementation.

Comment: Which API demo? There's a lot of them...